# Save the most recent months of a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes. Something like this...

```
transactions = [{"date"=>"2014-07-21", "amount"=>200},
               {"date"=>"2012-06-21", "amount"=>400},
               {"date"=>"2014-08-21", "amount"=>100},
               {"date"=>"2014-08-12", "amount"=>150},
               {"date"=>"2014-06-15", "amount"=>230}
               {"date"=>"2013-05-21", "amount"=>900},]
```

I want to be able to save each months total amounts and then show the most recent 3 months to todays date and their total amount. Something like this...

Totals:   06-14    $230
          07-14    $200
          08-14    $250

I have this method but i am not sure how to get only the last 3 months to put in my database field and how to print it out.

```
def income_by_month
    @payroll_transactions = current_user.transactions
    @recent_payroll = @payroll_transactions.find_all {90.days.ago.to_date..Date.today}.map #finds transactions within 90 days
     @amount_by_month = @recent_payroll.group_by { |t| t.date.to_date.month }.map do |month, transactions|
        [month, transactions.sum(:amount)] #Groups transactions by month and adds month total
      end.to_h
```

-EDIT-

I figured out a method to only get the transactions from the last 30 days I updated my method to show it. Now my question is how do I save the answer (Do i save it in one field as an Array?) and then how to show the answer in my view. Like I show it here. How do I print each key and value line by line in an order?

```
Totals:   06-14    $230
          07-14    $200
          08-14    $250
```

-EDIT-
Sorry my database is a mongoid db. And I want to save the most recent 3 months to todays date regardless of if an amount is available.

Comment: could you please clarify if you ask only to show a way to get the last 3 elements or also how to push that data to the database?
in a latter case you should give more insights of how your database is designed and how to you want to store that data.

Comment: Sorry my database is a mongoid db. And I want to save the most recent 3 months to todays date regardless of if amount is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start with a quick note on your code snippet:

```
group_by { |t| t.date.to_date.month }
```

Note that grouping objects by a single `month` does not take a year in count, so it would end summing up amounts for transactions of both 2012 and 2014 years in a one container. So what you really want is to group based on both month and year values.

Thinking of reducing the amount of redundant iterations through the input array (and using unnecessary aggregations), I've came to the following suggestion:

```
last_months = transactions.map{|i| Date.parse(i["date"]).strftime("%m-%Y")}.uniq.sort.last(3)
result      = last_months.inject({}){|result, input| result[input] = 0; result}
transactions.inject(result) do |result, object|
  # NOTE: we're already doing dates parsing and strftime two times here.
  # In case you operate on Date objects themselves in your code, this is not the case.
  # But the real perfomance measurement between summing all values up
  # and strftiming more than once should be done additionally.
  month = Date.parse(object["date"]).strftime("%m-%Y")
  result[month] += object["amount"] if result[month]
  result
end
# result now equals to {"06-2014"=>230, "07-2014"=>200, "08-2014"=>250}
```

First, we obtain those last three months (and years).
Next we create a hash to contain aggregated values with only those last months keys. At the end we sum up `amount` for only those transactions which seem to be one of the latter 3 months.

So, as long as ruby hashes (ruby v.1.9+) preserve the keys order, you can simply iterate over them to print out:

```
result.each{|k,v| puts "#{k}: #{v}"}
# 06-2014: 230
# 07-2014: 200
# 08-2014: 250
```

One last thing to note here is that doing this kind of aggregation inside of your server code is not quite efficient. Much more tempting option would be to move this calculations to your database layer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I am about to try it out. Question, this aggregation is in my model. Do you mean the printout should be within the model level or the entire aggregation of the info? I just want clarification.

Comment: my advice would be to write `SQL` query which retrieves desired information about transactions (instead of mapping and injecting hashes, like what you're doing now).

Comment: The transactions are an array of hashes from my database so i am not sure i can call an sql query. I thought calling all transactions in a date range like @transactions.find_all { |t| Date.parse( t["date"]) >= 180.days.from_now.to_date}.map but it keeps telling me bad date range

Answer (score 0):

ActiveSupport has some pretty slick date methods like Date#beginning_of_month:

```ruby
require "date"
require "active_support/core_ext"

def process_transaction_group(month, transactions)
  {
    month: month.strftime("%Y/%m"),
    total: transactions.map {|t| t["amount"] }.reduce(:+)
  }
end

def process_transactions(transactions)
  transactions
    .group_by {|t| Date.parse(t["date"]).beginning_of_month }
    .select {|month, _trxs| month < 3.months.ago }
    .map {|month, trxs| process_transaction_group(month, trxs) }
end

###############

transactions = [{"date"=>"2014-07-21", "amount"=>200},
               {"date"=>"2012-06-21", "amount"=>400},
               {"date"=>"2014-08-21", "amount"=>100},
               {"date"=>"2014-08-12", "amount"=>150},
               {"date"=>"2014-06-15", "amount"=>230},
               {"date"=>"2013-05-21", "amount"=>900}]

process_transactions(transactions)
#=> [{:month=>"2014/07", :total=>200}, {:month=>"2012/06", :total=>400}, {:month=>"2014/08", :total=>250}, {:month=>"2014/06", :total=>230}, {:month=>"2013/05", :total=>900}]
```